# How to detect route changes using React Router in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a search component that is global to my application, and displays search results right at the top. Once the user does any sort of navigation, e.g., clicking a search result or using the back button on the browser, *I want to reset the search: clear the results and the search input field*.

Currently, I am handling this with a `Context`; I have a `SearchContext.Provider` that broadcasts the `resetSearch` function, and wherever I am handling navigation, I have consumers that invoke `resetSearch` before processing navigation (which I do programmatically with the `useHistory` hook).

This doesn't work for back button presses on the browser's controls (since that is something out of my control).

Is there an intermediate step before my `Routes` are rendered (or any browser navigation happens) that I can hook into, to make sure my `resetSearch` function is invoked?

As requested, here is the code:

```
// App.js
const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

const resetSearch = () => {
    setResults([]);
    setQuery("");
};

<SearchContext.Provider value={{ resetSearch }}>
    // all of my <Route /> components in this block
</SearchContext.Provider>
```

```
// BusRoute.js
const { resetSearch } = useContext(SearchContext);

const handleClick = stop => {
    resetSearch();
    history.push(`/stops/${stop}`);
};

return (
    // some other JSX
    <button onClick={() => handleClick(stop.code)}>{stop.name}</button>
);
```

Comment: Can you not use the useEffect hook for this?

Comment: Could you provide some code? It's hard to understand exactly what you have now and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen to [`history`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#basic-usage) changes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const unlisten = history.listen((location) => {
    console.log('new location: ', location)
    // do your magic things here
    // reset the search: clear the results and the search input field
  })
  return function cleanup() {
    unlisten()
  }
}, [])
```

You can use this effect in your parent component which controls your global search's value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `componentWillUnmount` feature from class components with `useEffect` in hooks with functional component