# Nested routes inside a route not working - React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a page which has three routes. The 3rd route has a tab component which handles 3 sub routes. I am able to navigate to Route 3, but unable to view the tabs and unable to render the content under each tab.

Please advice.

This is my code:

```
import "./styles.scss";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router";
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Tab, Tabs } from "@blueprintjs/core";

const ComponentC1 = () => <p>Component C1</p>;
const ComponentC2 = () => <p>Component C2</p>;
const ComponentC3 = () => <p>Component C3</p>;

const componentCRoutes = [
  {
    label: "Component C - 1",
    code: "subC1",
    component: ComponentC1
  },
  {
    label: "Component C - 2",
    code: "subC2",
    component: ComponentC2
  },
  {
    label: "Component C - 3",
    code: "subC3",
    component: ComponentC3
  }
];
const ComponentA = () => <p>Component A</p>;
const ComponentB = () => <p>Component B</p>;
const ComponentC = (props) => {
  const [tabId, setTabId] = useState(componentCRoutes[0].label);

  const handleTabChange = (tabId) => setTabId(tabId);
  return (
    <>
      <p>Component C</p>
      <Tabs onChange={handleTabChange} selectedTabId={tabId}>
        {componentCRoutes.map((tab) => {
          return (
            <Tab
              key={tab.code}
              id={tab.label}
              title={
                <Link to={`/${props.match.url}/${tab.code}`}>{tab.label}</Link>
              }
            />
          );
        })}
      </Tabs>
      {(() => {
        const { component, code } = componentCRoutes.find(
          (item) => item.label === tabId
        );
        return (
          <Route path={`${props.match.url}/${code}`} component={component} />
        );
      })()}
      <Route exact path={props.match.url}>
        <Redirect to={`${props.match.url}/${componentCRoutes[0].code}`} />
      </Route>
    </>
  );
};

const routes = [
  { label: "Component A", path: "/routeA", component: ComponentA },
  { label: "Component B", path: "/routeB", component: ComponentB },
  { label: "Component C", path: "/routeC", component: ComponentC }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <BrowserRouter>
        {routes.map((item) => (
          <Link key={item.path} to={item.path} style={{ paddingRight: "10px" }}>
            {item.label}
          </Link>
        ))}
        <Switch>
          {routes.map((route) => {
            return (
              <Route
                key={route.path}
                exact
                path={route.path}
                component={route.component}
              />
            );
          })}
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Redirect to="/routeA" />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-ptolemy-5mn1v?file=/src/App.js:0-2693)

Please advice.

Comment: If a `Route` has nested Routes, it should not be exact. So you need `exact={false}` for the one that has nested routes. https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Comment: @AjeetShah Thanks. That fixed rendering the tabs. However when I click on those tabs, I get Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://routec/subC2' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://sw231.csb.app' and URL 'https://sw231.csb.app/routeC/subC1'. Below is my codesandbox link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-goldstine-sw231?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issues:

1. `Tabs` in `ComponentC` are not working correctly as React-Router `Link`. It can be fixed using `history.push` in Tab's `onChange` handler.
2. You have not defined *Routes* in your nested component properly. You are using `find` to define the `Route`, that looks dirty. It can be fixed using a `Switch` and `Route` in nested component i.e. `ComponentC`
3. You used `Route` and `Redirect` to make default paths. That can be simplified as well.
4. You used `props.match.url` and `props.match.path` *incorrectly*. `props.match.url` (URL) should be used in `Link` or `history.push` and `props.match.path` (PATH) should be used in **path** of your nested Routes declarations.

#### Solution:

After fixing all the issues mentioned above, Here is the working code:

(Also, note that the `Route` that has *nested* routes should **not** be marked `exact={true}`)

**Main Routes:**

```
const routes = [
  { exact: true, label: "Component A", path: "/routeA", component: ComponentA },
  { exact: true, label: "Component B", path: "/routeB", component: ComponentB }
  { exact: false, label: "Component C", path: "/routeC", component: ComponentC }
  // ^ it is false because it has nested routes
];

// JSX
<BrowserRouter>

  {routes.map((item) => (
    <Link key={item.path} to={item.path}>
      {item.label}
    </Link>
  ))}

  <Switch>
    {routes.map((route) => {
      return (
        <Route
          key={route.path}
          exact={route.exact}
          path={route.path}
          component={route.component}
        />
      );
    })}
    <Redirect exact from="/" to="/routeA" />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And Here is **nested routes** declarations inside **ComponentC**:

```
const routes = [
  {
    label: "Component C1",
    code: "subC1",
    component: ComponentC1
  },
  {
    label: "Component C2",
    code: "subC2",
    component: ComponentC2
  },
  {
    label: "Component C3",
    code: "subC3",
    component: ComponentC3
  }
];

export default function ComponentC(props) {
  const [tabId, setTabId] = useState(routes[0].code);
  const handleTabChange = (tabId) => {
    props.history.push(`${props.match.url}/${tabId}`);
    setTabId(tabId);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Tabs onChange={handleTabChange} selectedTabId={tabId}>
        {routes.map((tab) => {
          return <Tab key={tab.code} id={tab.code} title={tab.label} />;
        })}
      </Tabs>

      <Switch>
        {routes.map((route) => (
          <Route
            key={route.code}
            exact
            path={`${props.match.path}/${route.code}`}
            component={route.component}
          />
        ))}
        <Redirect
          exact
          from={props.match.url}
          to={`${props.match.url}/${routes[0].code}`}
        />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is full demo on [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-nested-routes-exjkk).

Comment: Thanks Ajeet. Can you just hint me on a specific question? Lets say I have queryParams to be carried over on each route. E.g.: /routeA?id=4 and I need it to be carried over to /routeC/subC3?id=4 but it fails.

Comment: I think there is no way to automatically forward this. You will have to write manual code. See [query-parameters in doc](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters). It is possible to pass Query Params with `Link`, `history.push`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66610677/2873538). **May be**, you can write some manual code using [this listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66404585/2873538) which can forward Query Params automatically. Try this, if you fail, maybe you can ask a new question : "How to forward query params automatically?". Maybe someone knows solution.

Comment: Thanks @AjeetShah

Comment: BUT wait, if it is being passed automatically on Each Route. Why not just make it a permanent part of route, using [route param] -> you can find this in docs. https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params You can decide.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look

Comment: I was able to fix it by manually adding search to history.push with the necessary value

Comment: I have one more nested route inside ComponentC3, but it doesnt render. Can you help me out on this or do you want me to ask a new question? https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-nested-routes-forked-2pe0z?file=/src/ComponentC.js

Comment: @a2441918 Done: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-nested-routes-forked-denfq

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again. I think this is the final piece. Whenever I click on Take me to a new route, I need the url changes but the new component is rendered just below Component C3 content. I want it in a way where the componentC3 content is removed and only subComponentC3 is shown below the tab. I can create a new question if that works out for you.